# If array sizes can only be a constant value than what does char d_name[...] mean?

Tags: c, linux, arrays

If array sizes can only be a constant value than what does

```
   char d_name[...]
```

mean?

Actually, there is a struct dirent declared in dirent.h file. its declaration is as under:

```
struct dirent{
  ....
  ino_t d_ino;
  char d_name[...];
  ...
  };
```

It is used to read directory contents one at a time i.e. inode numbers and filenames etc...

I mean what is the max size of such an array and how much space is statically allocated in the memory once such an array is defined? Is such a definition portable?

Comment: Where did you find that? In what context?

Comment: And if wishes were horses... but in C, array sizes need not be constant expressions.

Comment: such a declaration is there in struct dirent used to read directory contents in linux os. I could not find much about the declaration itself except it was used to store filenames in the directory.

Comment: now would the down-voters please retract?

Comment: @bhuwansahni: where did you read that syntax exactly?

Comment: @Mat: The book Linux Programming by example by arnold robbins gives the definition as specifird in the ques...

Comment: :) guess it's like the answer says, you `malloc` the structure and the array assumes some size accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming it's from `struct linux_dirent`, it's actually char `d_name[]` :

```
struct linux_dirent {
    unsigned long  d_ino;     /* Inode number */
    unsigned long  d_off;     /* Offset to next linux_dirent */
    unsigned short d_reclen;  /* Length of this linux_dirent */
    char           d_name[];  /* Filename (null-terminated) */
}
```

It's called a flexible array member, using `malloc` you can allocate more memory to the struct giving `d_name` a variable size.

#### EDIT

The text the OP is quoting:

> Directory entries are represented by a struct dirent
>
> ```
> struct dirent {
>     ...
>     ino_t d_ino;            /* XSI extension --- see text */
>     char  d_name[...];      /* See text on the size of this array */
> ...
> };
> ```

With the `...` the authors signals the size isn't fixed **per standard**. Each implementation must choose a fixed size, for example Linux chooses 256. But it's not valid code.

Comment: But my book Linux Programming by Example by arnold robbins gives the definition as specified in the ques....

Comment: Well then your book is at best using non-C notation to convey an abstract concept (implementation-defined length) to the reader without clearly stating this, and at worst just plain wrong. It certainly won't be the first time a programming book was wrong... :-)

Comment: @R.. I read that section and that's exactly what it's doing. Simple really, but quite confusing if you don't know `d_name[...]` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: How will you use malloc here to give some size to the array d_name, I mean the syntax..

Comment: @bhuwansahni If `d_name` were defined `char d_name[]`, you would simply malloc more memory than the rest of the structure. The surplus would automatically go to `d_name`.